# SP 2010 - Web Part to display a list of pages from parent site filtered by metadata

Tags: content-query-web-part

I have a SubSite that I need to have a web part that will show a list of articles that are stored on the parent site.  There is a metadata tag called "vendors" that each article is associated to.

Is there an OOTB web part that will allow me to display a list of articles filtered by the metadata?

I created a view within the Pages document library where the pages are located.  Within the view I made it display the page title and filtered it by the metadata field.  It shows just the articles that I want.

My trouble is finding the right web part to display the list.  I have a Subsite within a subsite that I'd like this to display on.  I tried the web part that is located under Lists and Libraries and called Documents.  This seems to be restricted to only looking at the Documents folder within this subsite.  There is a field in the properties called Title URL under Advanced, that lets me point to another location, but it still doesn't seem to take me there.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for any help you can give!

Matt

Answer (score 1):

The [Content Query Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/display-data-from-multiple-lists-with-the-content-query-web-part-HA010174134.aspx) might be what you are looking for.  Simply add it to the page, edit it, point the Query to the list you wish to include data from and set the filter to your metadata field.

Comment: Problem with the CQWP is that it requires the publishing infrastructure feature to be activated in the site collection.